# How to use a SQL Server database table for authentication instead of the IdentityUsers default table

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, identity

I have identity set up in my project right now. It is working with the default `IdentityUsers` table to log in.

There is an existing `Employees` table in a SQL Server database that has an `Email` and a `User_Password` column that they want to use for the log in.

Is there an easy way to change this? I'm still fairly new to this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "change this"?

Comment: Meaning to use the Employee table in the SQL Server database instead of the IdentityUsers Table that it is currenty linked to.

Comment: rename doesn't work?